# Corona: Error Loading Module Error

Tags: module, lua, coronasdk

I am creating a OOP game in Corona SDK using metatables and am having some trouble with my code.

Here is my main.lua file:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Your code here

local hero = require("hero")
local environment = require("environment")
local obstacle = require("obstacle")

local player = hero.new("Billy", 0, 10)
```

Here is my hero.lua class file:

```
local hero = {}
local hero_mt = {_index = hero}

--Constructor

function hero.new (name, positionX, positionY)
    local newHero = {
        name = name
        positionX = positionX or 0
        positionY = positionY or 0
    }

    return setmetatable( newHero, herp_mt )

function hero:Jump(amount)

end
```

And the error I am receiving is as follows:

error loading module 'hero' from file 'hero.lua':
hero.lua:14 '}' expected (to close '{' at line 12) near 
'positionX'

I followed the same syntax this site used (https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/)
but still nothing is working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing commas when declaring your newHero table. All tables must have their properties separated by commas. See the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html) for more information. The last element can have a comma as well.

```
local newHero = {
    name = name,
    positionX = positionX or 0,
    positionY = positionY or 0,
}
```

You are missing a closing `end` as well for the function `hero.new()` And need to return the hero table at the end of your hero file, like so: `return hero` so that you can actually call `hero.new()` in your main file.